# One q-binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

There is an identity on $q$-binomial coefficients: $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^i{{2n}\choose{i}}_q = (1-q)(1-q^3)\ldots(1-q^{2n-1})$. Does anybody know where one can look for a proof or how to prove it?
I used the q-binomial theorem in order to rewrite $(1-q)(1-q^3)\ldots(1-q^{2n-1})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k^2}{{n}\choose{k}}_{q^2}$. But this is still far from the sum I would like to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathan Azose’s 2007 Harvey Mudd College undergraduate thesis, [*Applications of the q-Binomial Coefficients to Counting Problems*](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1194&context=hmc_theses), introduces a nice combinatorial interpretation of the $q$-binomial coefficients and in Section 3.2 uses it to prove the desired result fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: @tep12: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Prof, Are there any connection between these q-binomial coefficient and integrals of the form $\int_0^{\infty} R(\cos x, \sin x ) ^n$ ? Where $R$ is rational

Comment: @James: I’m not aware of any, but I’m not very knowledgeable about either topic.

Comment: What topic would this strictly belong? I am asking so I can search literature.

Comment: @James: If there is anything, you’d probably have better luck starting on the $q$-binomial coefficient side, and $q$-combinatorics generally, but I really don’t know enough even to offer good pointers.